# Comparing and formating text from 2 files in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I need your help again. 
I have two files, which contain this:

FILE1

```
print_recursive.o   print_ackermann
print_recursive.o   print_fib_upto
timeout.o   timeout
recursive.o    ackermann
```

FILE2

```
recfun.o    print_ackermann
recfun.o    print_fib_upto
print_recursive.o   timeout
recfun.o    strtoul
```

What I need to do, is take second column from both files, find those, which are the same, (that is the "symbol which connects them) - sorry for my bad english.
Then, I need to print it like this:

```
FILE2_first column -> FILE1_first column (second column_if_they_match)
example:
recfun.o -> print_recursive.o (print_ackermann)
recfun.o -> print_recursive.o (print_fib_upto)
print_recursive.o -> timeout.o (timeout)
```

Which means, that if it finds the same symbol (column2 of both files), it will get names of modules from first  columns and print it together. I know i should use awk/grep/sed or so, but I have no clue how.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1;next} $2 in a{print $1, "->", a[$2], "(" $2 ")"}' f1 f2
recfun.o -> print_recursive.o (print_ackermann)
recfun.o -> print_recursive.o (print_fib_upto)
print_recursive.o -> timeout.o (timeout)
```

Comment: @jaypal: I was little slow on the other awk question which you answered fastest and accurately so I had to make up for it :)